# "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field" when using OrderedDict

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I try to run an aggregate command:

```js
request = collections.OrderedDict([
        ("$unwind", "$tags" ),
        ("$group", { "_id" : "$tags" , "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }  } ),
        ("$project", { "_id" : 0, "tag" : "$_id" , "count" : 1 } ),
        ("$sort", { "count" : -1 } ),
        ("$limit", 3 )])

print client.devoxx.talks.aggregate(request)
```

But MongoDB rejects it:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', u'talks'), ('pipeline', [OrderedDict([('$unwind', '$tags'), ('$group', {'count': {'$sum': 1}, '_id': '$tags'}), ('$project', {'count': 1, '_id': 0, 'tag': '$_id'}), ('$sort', {'count': -1}), ('$limit', 3)])])]) failed: exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
```

It seems to me that I have each aggregate stage in one item of the ordered dict.

Comment: If you could reproduce this without using pymongo, it would be clearer and you could remove the possibly irrelevant python tag.

Comment: @ErikAllik I furthermore say the tag is not valid and removed. And the statement is not necessary because an un-ordered Dict is not a valid argument for the method being called.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probaby very pymongo specific but it is also very unnecessary  as the standard form of arguments for an aggregation pipeline is actually an array and may as well be simply specified like so, for example:

```python
request = [{ "$unwind": "$tags"}, { "$group": { "_id": "$tags" } }]
```

Which is always going to serialize in order and as such presents no problem.

So there is no need to use an OrderedDict.

You are perhaps confusing the behavior with recent changes to the mongo shell (from 2.6) that allows arguments to be specified without wrapping in an array. But JSON as with some other languages expects their "dictionary/hash" definitions to maintain their specified order.

So using an array/list syntax is **still** the preferred implementation.